# How to do left join and create an indicator for matched/unmatched records?

Tags: sql, sas

I want to create a left join with indicator, so that for matched records, i can put an indicator 1 and for unmatched records i can put an indicator 0, while selecting the data?

Comment: can I do it in t-sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in T-SQL

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Table2.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Match
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement in the `SELECT` in order to check if the column you join on in the right-hand column `IS NULL`.

For example, to list all employees, along with their manager, and a boolean flag indicated whether they have a manager or not, use this:

```
select
  e.first_name,
  e.last_name,
  case
    when m.employee_id is not null then 1
    else 0
  end as has_manager
  m.first_name as manager_first_name,
  m.last_name as manager_last_name
from employee e
left outer join manager m on m.employee_id = e.manager_id;
```